# Why scanf("%s",&str); behaves as scanf("%s",str);?

Tags: c, pointers, scanf, pointer-arithmetic

Look at the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[80];
    int n;
    scanf("%s%n",str,&n);
    printf("%s\t%d",str,n);
    putchar('\n');
    getchar(); //to remove '\n'
    scanf("%s%n",&str,&n);
    printf("%s\t%d",str,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the input and output:

```
abc
abc     3
123
123     3
```

As we know, `scanf` is a variable parametric function, so its parameters will not be cast when it's called. As a result, parameters must be passed in the **type** exactly what them should be. However, the type of `str` is `char *` (decayed from `char (*)[80]`), while `&str` has the type of `char (*)[80]`, although they have the same **value**, namely `&str[0]`.

So why can `scanf("%s",&str);` work properly without causing segfault due to **pointer arithmetic**?

Comment: You are just very lucky

Comment: What? *pointer* or *address-of-pointer*, it's all the same right?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: `str` is not a pointer, but an array.

Comment: Because undefined behaviour includes "does what I wanted".

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406935/reading-a-string-with-scanf

Comment: Statement `scanf("%s%n",&str,&n);` yields a warning in gcc 4.8.4.

Comment: Using `&str` invokes undefined behavior. It "works" in this case because on your system (1) the representation of the two pointer types (`char *` and `char (*)[80]`) happen to be the same (2) they have the same address, and (3) the cast does not cause the representation to change.

Comment: "the type of str is char * (decayed from char (*)[80])" - no, the type of `str` is `char [80]`, which decays to `char *`. A subtle but important difference.

Comment: This is also partly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34557160/what-will-happen-if-is-not-put-in-a-scanf-statement-in-c

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two pointer values (`str` and `&str`) have the same binary value, namely the address of `str`.  They do, however, have different types:  When passed as an argument, `str` is converted to type `char *`, while `&str` has type `char (*)[80]`.  The former is correct, while the latter is incorrect.  It works, but you are using an incorrect pointer type, and in fact `gcc` warns about the incorrect argument type to `scanf`.

Comment: str has type char[80], but it decays to char*.

Comment: Yes, that's true.  When passed as an argument, it becomes `char *`.

Comment: It's nothing to do with being passed as an argument. An array decays to a pointer in many usages. It is however wrong to refer to `str` as a _pointer_, as you do in the first sentence of your answer.

Comment: I reworded it slightly to avoid confusion.  My statement about `str` being converted to `char *` when passed as an argument was entirely correct.  I never said that was the *only* situation in which that conversion took place, and of course it isn't.

Comment: It's still wrong: "str has type char * (when passed as an argument)" - no, `str` is of type "80 element array of `char`", it doesn't have any other type no matter how it is used. The process of decay is a _conversion_, the value is no longer the original value (i.e. it is not `str` anymore). So you could say for instance : "The value of `str` decays to a value of type `char *` (when passed as an argument)" and this would be correct. Even "`str` decays to a value of type `char *` ..." would be better IMO.

Comment: @davmac I see your point.  I reworded it slightly.

Comment: @TomKarzes it's better now, thanks (upvoted).