# scanf replaces last elements in char array with the next scanf input

Tags: c, pointers

I've come a cross a problem where, when I'm using scanf to store a string into a char pointer, I have 3 inputs - name, surname, and age, that surname's last char value get replaced by age here's the output to better explain.

> Q-riosity v0.0.1
>   Enter your name
>   Evgeny
>   Enter your surname
>   Danilenko
>   Enter your age
>   22
>   Evgeny Danilenk22, you are 22 years old

Here's the code

```
void getUserDetails(char** value)
{
    char *key[3] = {"name", "surname", "age"};
    int keySize = sizeof(key)/sizeof(char*);
    printf("Q-riosity v0.0.1\n");

    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i<keySize; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter your %s \n", key[i]); // name, surname, age
        scanf("%s", &value[i]);             //stores value at index i
    }

    printf("%s, %s, you are %s years old\n", &value[0], &value[1], &value[2]);
}
```

**EDIT**

Enter your name
Evgeny
Enter your surname
Danilenko
Enter your age
22
Segmentation fault

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    char *key[3] = {"name", "surname", "age"};
    int keySize = sizeof(key)/sizeof(char*);
    printf("Q-riosity v0.0.1\n");
    char* value[keySize];

    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i<keySize; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter your %s \n", key[i]);
        scanf("%s", value[i]);
    }


    for(i = 0; i<keySize; i++)
    {
        printf("%s : %s \n", key[i], value[i]);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: remove the all the `&` from the last `printf`

Comment: Where is declaration for value? How much memory you are allocating for that?

Comment: Nadir, if i do so, ill get a segmentation error

Comment: `char* value[keySize];` is an array of 3 pointers pointer to who-knows-what.  `scanf("%s", value[i]);` will certainly fail.  Need to allocate/define space to save input.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a `char**` to both `printf` and `scanf`. The `%s`s expect `char*`s, not `char**`s. So, replace the following:

```
scanf("%s", &value[i]);
printf("%s, %s, you are %s years old\n", &value[0], &value[1], &value[2]);
```

with

```
scanf("%s", value[i]);
printf("%s, %s, you are %s years old\n", value[0], value[1], value[2]);
```

---

The new code has one problem:

```
char* value[keySize];
```

creates an array of size `keySize` of pointers to `char`. These pointers are uninitialized and could be pointing to anywhere. You write to these uninitialized pointers via `scanf` and this invokes the famous Undefined Behavior.

Solutions for this include:

1. `malloc` memory for each pointer.
2. Make the pointers point to some valid memory location as shown in [@SergeBallesta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3545273/serge-ballesta)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36133363/3049655).
3. Use a 2D array:

   ```
   char value[keySize][64];
   ```

Comment: Actually before I came up with that solution, i had exact same code you are suggesting me, however, i am getting segmentation error. also im not using malloc anywhere, im just passing passing input, to vars. I'll update the post with my previous code, so you'll see it for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, the output `Danilenk22` suggests that your `value` variable was declared in caller as consecutive char arrays with size 8.

When you read `Danilenko` as surname, you write 10 characters (including the terminating `\0`. The first 8 fill the reserved array, the last 2 go in array for age. When you later read the age, it overrides those 2 characters.

Lets look at memory (? represent unitialized or don't care characters):

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
   E  v  g  e  n  y \0  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?
   E  v  g  e  n  y \0  ?  D  a  n  i  l  e  n  k  o \0  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?
   E  v  g  e  n  y \0  ?  D  a  n  i  l  e  n  k  2  2 \0  ?  ?  ?  ?  ?
```

But eight characters could also be the size of a pointer on a 64 bits architecture...

Your edit shows that you fail to initialize correctly the `value` array of pointers. Assuming that you want to have 32 characters for name and surname, and 4 for the age, you could do:

```
char _v0[32], _v1[32], _v2[4];
char* value[keySize] = { _v0, _v1, _v2 };
```

That way the program no longer seg fault.

Comment: Yea i think thats one of the reasons. I tried writing surname first, then name, etc, now the surname is concatenated with the name... How would i go about it? I am running a 64 bit machine

Answer (score 1):

Replace line

```
printf("%s, %s, you are %s years old\n", &value[0], &value[1], &value[2]);
```

with

```
printf("%s, %s, you are %s years old\n", value[0], value[1], value[2]);
```

Remember, you want to print a value, not its address.

**NOTE :** `scanf()` requires a pointer in order to read properly, so its syntax is

```
scanf("%s", &str);
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", &str);` is wrong if `str` is defined as `char str[SOME_SIZE];`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `value` is well-malloced before it's passed:

Simply change the `printf()` statement to

```
printf("%s, %s, you are %s years old\n", value[0], value[1], value[2]);
```

and your `scanf()` statement to

```
scanf("%s", value[i]);
```

---

In fact, `printf("%s", &str)` invokes undefined behaviour, although it usually works properly. This is because `str` and `&str` have different types, despite the fact that their values are identical. To verify this, simply run

```
printf("%p\n%p\n%p\n%p", (void *)str, (void *)(str + 1), (void *)&str, (void *)(&str + 1));
```

See also: [Why scanf("%s",&str); behaves as scanf("%s",str);?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34704302/5399734)