# Applied Switch and it closes?

Tags: c

So i am just starting to learn c programming and **i decided to practice by making my program speak to the end-user** by **asking questions** and **reacting to
 them**

I first applied **if-else statement** for the program to react on the age of the person.
then,  when i get to the *whats your favorite color part with the switch statements* it would just close upon pressing any button.

**My code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <ctype.h>

 main()
 {

 char name[25], c;
 int a;
 clrscr();

 printf("Hello, whats your name? \n");
 scanf("%s",name); 
 printf("nice to meet you %s!!!\n");

 printf("Whats your age?");
 scanf("%d",&a");
     {
      if((a <= 21) && (a >= 0))
        printf("Young!\n");

      else if((a <= 100) && (a >= 22))
       printf("old!\n");

      else
       printf("that's not an age!\n");
     }

printf("whats your favorite color? \n"); //this is where the program stops//
scanf("%c",&c);
  switch(tolower(c)){
    case 'r':printf("Fiery!");break;
    case 'o':printf("oranggerrr!!");break;  
     .
     . //basically applied the whole rainbow and put some reactions// 
     .

getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the question is.

Comment: It's look like he/she is asking why it's working. Written in comments

Comment: sorry i just edited.  ^-^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I compiled the program online [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php), making some changes, as the program you have given only compiles in the old Turbo C.

I compiled the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <conio.h>
//#include <dos.h>
#include <ctype.h>

 main()
 {

 char name[25], c;
 int a;
 //clrscr();

 printf("Hello, whats your name? \n");
 scanf("%s",name); //still dont get why it worked without the "&"//
 printf("nice to meet you %s!!!\n");

 printf("Whats your age?");
 scanf("%d",&a);
     {
      if((a <= 21) && (a >= 0))
        printf("Young!\n");

      else if((a <= 100) && (a >= 22))
       printf("old!\n");

      else
       printf("that's not an age!\n");
     }

printf("whats your favorite color? \n"); //this is where the program stops//
scanf("%c",&c);
  switch(c){
    case 'r':printf("Fiery!");break;
    case 'o':printf("oranggerrr!!");break;  
    // .
     //. //basically applied the whole rainbow and put some reactions// 
     //.
  }

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Okay, so when I executed it, I got a segmentation fault, because of this line:

```
printf ("nice to meet you %s!!!\n");
```

to

```
printf ("nice to meet you %s!!!\n", name);
```

Then everything worked perfectly.

Now your doubt:

- `scanf ("%s", name);`
  *That works because name is a char array, and the name of an   array is equal to the address of the first element in that array*. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34557160/what-will-happen-if-is-not-put-in-a-scanf-statement-in-c#comment56857317_34557176) comment. Also, you can see the question.

Improvements:

- Change `scanf ("%c", &c);` to `scanf (" %c", &c);`

**NOTE:** I cannot exactly reproduce your problem as I do not have Turbo C. Also, maybe your program crashed because of `tolower`. Note that `tolower` return the changed char, so you will have to do: `c = tolower (c);`